# Logging .map() to console roughly shows what i want yet the same line of code added via innerHTML only shows the last item

Tags: javascript, arrays

After stalking Stack Overflow for a bit I finally made an account and this is my first time actually posing a question.

So I recently started playing with APIs to get better at web development. After building an anime info app that I enjoyed, I started another project but for NHL teams and rosters using an API from here: https://gitlab.com/dword4/nhlapi/-/blob/master/stats-api.md

Team info and logos portion works well, yet I am trying to pull the roster for each team and that's where my breakage starts. Using .map() in my function results in somewhat of what I want in console, but the same code when added to .innerHTML only results in the last player's name, not the whole roster. I've added for loops and tried chaining promises but with no luck.

If anyone could maybe point me in the right direction would be super appreciated.

```
 function getRosterByID(teamID){
  fetch(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${teamID}/roster`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.roster.map(players => {
      console.log(players.person.fullName);
      roster.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <dl>
          <dt>${players.person.fullName}</dt>
        </dl>
      </div>`;
    }).join();
    roster.style.display = 'flex';
  });
}
```

Comment: `roster.innerHTML =` will set the entire contents to the string on the right. Anything that existed previously in the element will be removed. You want `+=` instead. You should also remove the `.map` and use `forEach` instead - `.map` is for constructing a new array, not for generic side-effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use innerHTML it does not append. It is a flat out replacement. You should also not use map() as a loop, that is what foreach is for.

But using map, you can get all the text

```
 function getRosterByID(teamID){
  fetch(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${teamID}/roster`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    const htmlOut = data.roster.map(players => {
      console.log(players.person.fullName);
      return  `
      <div>
        <dl>
          <dt>${players.person.fullName}</dt>
        </dl>
      </div>`;
    }).join('');
    roster.innerHTML = htmlOut;
    roster.style.display = 'flex';
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your example above does work. Although, for the life of me the forEach I cannot get. Again console says what I want but everything appended to an HTML element shows undefined.

Comment: map() is the way to go for this. I have no clue why your way of doing it with forEach would not work without seeing what you did.

Comment: So I made a jsfiddle account too thinking that it might be a bit easier to show what I've done. The final view looks a little off since i haven't added media queries and the team logos .jpgs aren't on the fiddle. The commented out block in the getRosterByID function is what I've got working, the forEach in the same function is what I'm playing with. Also, if you wouldn't mind giving a little feedback on my code in general, I would much appreciate it. https://jsfiddle.net/naynayren/k8jg2mce/4/